# MySql multiple relations in new column

Tags: mysql, database, field

I have multiple tables with contact information for a number of different leads. There is a table with a list of ids and names '`leads`', a table with a list of ids and phone numbers '`phones`', and a table that links the two together `'lead_phones`'. Some contacts have multiple phone numbers for that one person. When I run a query that looks like this:

```
SELECT l.created,
    l.id,
    l.first_name,
    l.last_name,
    ph.number phone1,
    #IF(COUNT(ph.number) > 1, *second phone*, null) AS phone2,
    e.email email
FROM leads l
LEFT JOIN lead_phones lp ON lp.lead_id = l.id
LEFT JOIN phones ph on ph.id = lp.phone_id
LEFT JOIN lead_emails le ON le.lead_id = l.id
LEFT JOIN emails e on e.id = le.email_id
ORDER BY l.created DESC;
```

I get a table that looks like this

```
created             id    first_name last_name phone      email
2016-03-22 15:53:01 45620 Jimmy      Dean      5551234567 jdean@something.com
2016-03-22 15:53:00 45619 John       Smith     5554561234 smith@somethingelse.com
2016-03-22 15:51:54 45618 Betty      Boo       5552582585 betty@betty.com 
2016-03-22 15:50:02 45617 Betty      Boo       5551478965 betty@betty.com
```

What I would really like to do is be able to put Betty Boo on one row with phone 1 and phone 2. The commented line in my query was an attempt to get what I want I just couldn't figure out how to finish it.

Thanks

Comment: Can there ever be more than 2 phone numbers?  If so, you'll need to use `dynamic sql`... If not, there are a couple different ways to do this with aggregation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are attempting to `pivot` your results.  It's a little unclear which `id` field should be returned (expected results would help), but assuming you can only have a maximum of 2 phone numbers per lead, then here's one option using `min` and `max`:

```
SELECT max(l.created) created,
    max(l.id) id,
    l.first_name,
    l.last_name,
    min(ph.number) phone1,
    max(ph.number) phone2,
    e.email email
FROM leads l
    LEFT JOIN lead_phones lp ON lp.lead_id = l.id
    LEFT JOIN phones ph on ph.id = lp.phone_id
    LEFT JOIN lead_emails le ON le.lead_id = l.id
    LEFT JOIN emails e on e.id = le.email_id
GROUP BY l.first_name, l.last_name, e.email
```

Comment: Brilliant! Multiple groupings to get the rows to match on what I want and then use min and max to separate the two numbers. If I did have more than two I'm guessing some sort of range function exists and would be a solution. Thanks for the help.